# matplotlib: save multiple axis figure wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I am trying to plot a twin figure. my code seems to work correctly in jupyter notebooks. the output figure of jupyter notebooks are as follows
[jupyter notebook inline figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaISs.png)

However, when I try to save the figure to file, my output figure is always wrong, no matter how I adjust the figure size by `figsize=(*,*)` keywords, I can not get the right results. my output to file are something like the below figure
[save to file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7CT9.png)

my code as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)

box1 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4]
box2 = [0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8]

ax1.set_position(box1) #lower figure
ax2.set_position(box2) #upper figure

x=np.arange(10)
y1=0*x
y2=x+1

ax1.plot(x,y1)
ax2.plot(x,y2)
ax1.set_xlim(0,9)
ax2.set_xlim(0,9)
ax2.set_xticklabels('')

ax1.set_xlabel('ax1 x')
ax1.set_ylabel('ax1 y')
ax2.set_ylabel('ax2 x')
ax2.set_title('titles')

fig1.savefig('./1.png',dpi=200)
fig1.show()
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: pyplot is kind of tricky; is it any help to switch the last two lines?

Comment: thank you. seems still don't work properly.